# What's the common denominator for regex "pattern" in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI, which allows `pattern=re.compile("(?P<foo>[42a-z]+)...")`.

https://editor.swagger.io/ shows an error for this pattern.

My guess is that Python's named group syntax `(?P<name>...)` is different from ES2018 `(?<name>...)`.

But, come to think of it, the idea of OpenAPI is interoperability, and some other language, esp. a compiled language may use yet another notation, or may not support named groups in the regular expressions at all.

What common denominator of regular expression syntax should I use?

Answer (score 3):

OpenAPI uses json schema, and the json schema spec [defines regex](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3.8) as "A regular expression, which SHOULD be valid according to the ECMA-262 regular expression dialect." [Here is the relevant ECMA-262 section](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects).

Of course non-javascript implementations probably won't care too much about it, and just use the default regex library of their platform. So good luck with figuring out the common denominator :)

I suggest just using as simple regexes as possible. And add some tests for it, using the library that you use in production.

Answer (score 0):

Json Schema recommends a specific subset of regular expressions because the authors accept that most implementations will not support full `ECMA 262` syntax:

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html

> - A single unicode character (other than the special characters below) matches itself.
> - `.`: Matches any character except line break characters. (Be aware that what constitutes a line break character is somewhat dependent on your platform and language environment, but in practice this rarely matters).
> - `^`: Matches only at the beginning of the string.
> - `$`: Matches only at the end of the string.
> - `(...)`: Group a series of regular expressions into a single regular expression.
> - `|`: Matches either the regular expression preceding or following the `|` symbol.
> - `[abc]`: Matches any of the characters inside the square brackets.
> - `[a-z]`: Matches the range of characters.
> - `[^abc]`: Matches any character not listed.
> - `[^a-z]`: Matches any character outside of the range.
> - `+`: Matches one or more repetitions of the preceding regular expression.
> - `*`: Matches zero or more repetitions of the preceding regular expression.
> - `?`: Matches zero or one repetitions of the preceding regular expression.
> - `+?`, `*?`, `??`: The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behavior isn’t desired and you want to match as few characters as possible.
> - `(?!x)`, `(?=x)`: Negative and positive lookahead.
> - `{x}`: Match exactly `x` occurrences of the preceding regular expression.
> - `{x,y}`: Match at least `x` and at most `y` occurrences of the preceding regular expression.
> - `{x,}`: Match `x` occurrences or more of the preceding regular expression.
> - `{x}?`, `{x,y}?`, `{x,}?`: Lazy versions of the above expressions.

P.S. Kudos to @erosb for the idea how to find this recommendation.